# Deletion of node in singly linked list when pointer to the node is given. Assigning pointer doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my function:

```
void deleteAtPointer(struct node **toDel)
{
    printf("\ndeleteAtPointer");

    struct node *temp=NULL;
    temp=(*toDel)->next;

    //(*toDel)=temp->next;
    //free(temp);
    (*toDel)->next=temp->next;
    (*toDel)->data=temp->data;
    //(*toDel)=temp; //If I uncomment this line and comment the above two lines, the node doesn't get deleted. Why?
    free(temp);
}
```

Why does the assignment operator doesn't assign the pointer temp to (*toDel), while if I assign each of it's contents one by one, it works.

The node structure has an int type member along with a self-referential pointer.

Comment: You're not deleting at the given pointer, you're deleting its `next` pointer. What if `(*toDel)->next` is `NULL` ? You're even discarding `(*toDel)->data` here ...

Comment: @Chnossos: My idea is to copy the given pointer's next pointer to itself. I am able to delete the desired node this way. (*toDel)->next will be NULL in the case of the last node. That's a bug.

Comment: Removing a node simply mean doing something like `toDelPrev->next = toDel->next;` or `*head = (*head)->next;` if it is the first node. Keeping it simple is the best.

Comment: @Chnossos: But I have only got a pointer to the node to be deleted. I can't know what it's previous node is.

Comment: Is that a requirement ? You can't remove the node correctly if the previous node can't be changed (again, except for the first node).

Comment: @Chnossos: Yes, it's the requirement, rather an interview question.

Comment: @user3121023: Yes, you are correct. Thanks. You can answer the question and I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got this. Here is what happens if you use the commented code:

```
temp = (*toDel)->next;

┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ B │ →  │ C │ →  │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    └───┘    └───┘
           ↑        ↑
           toDel    temp

(*toDel) = temp->next;

┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ B │ →  │ C │ →  │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    └───┘    └───┘
                    ↑        ↑
                    temp     toDel

free(temp);

┌───┐    ┌───┐    ╔═══╗    ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ B │ →  ║XXX║ →  │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    ╚═══╝    └───┘
                    ↑        ↑
                    temp     toDel

(*toDel) = temp;

┌───┐    ┌───┐    ╔═══╗    ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ B │ →  ║XXX║ →  │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    ╚═══╝    └───┘
                    ↑
                    toDel / temp
```

Your node is invalidated, but `toDel` still points to it. Rather dangerous.

The uncommented code is the right one (don't forget the `NULL` test):

```
void deleteAtPointer (struct node ** toDel)
{
    if (toDel == NULL ││ *toDel == NULL)
        return ;

    struct node * temp = (*toDel)->next;

    if (temp)
    {
        (*toDel)->data = temp->data;
        (*toDel)->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        free(*toDel);
        *toDel = NULL;
    }
}
```

```
(*toDel)->data = temp->data;

┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐    ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ C │ →  │ C │ →  │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    └───┘    └───┘
           ↑        ↑
           toDel    temp

(*toDel)->next = temp->next;

                ┌───────┐
┌───┐    ┌───┐  │ ┌───┐ │   ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ C │ ─┘ │ C │ └─> │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    └───┘     └───┘
           ↑        ↑   
           toDel    temp

free(temp);

                ┌───────┐
┌───┐    ┌───┐  │ ╔═══╗ │   ┌───┐
│ A │ →  │ C │ ─┘ ║XXX║ └─> │ D │
└───┘    └───┘    ╚═══╝     └───┘
           ↑        ↑   
           toDel    temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!